# Стоит ли хранить данные в одном объекте вместе с EventEmitter

Tags: javascript, node.js

Вот подумал почему бы не хранить все данные в одном объекте, то есть у меня есть объект EventEmitter'а и у меня возникла мысль почему бы не хранить в нём данные.
то есть чтобы было

```
var myee = new EventEmitter();
myee.on()
myee.data = []
myee.objects = {data: value}
```

Насколько это может быть плохо с точки зрения замусоривания объекта EventEmitter'а

Comment: так делать можно и это обычная практика. почитай исходники любого модуля, хоть того же request

Comment: Понятно что объект он и в Африке объект, больше интересует как относится тот-же V8 к такому сочетанию, не сбрасывает ли он оптимизации при таком соседстве.

Comment: какие именно оптимизации? у EventEmitter есть removeAllListeners, вызывай его когда объект станет не нужен и тогда уж точно не будет проблем у сборщика мусора

Comment: Да у V8 много заморочек, например знаменитый баг с делением на ноль, ну не баг ,а особенность, то есть если где то при расчётах канваса одна из координат станет нулём и будет поделена то снимется вся оптимизация функции где это произошло,и таких моментов достаточно много, вот отсюда и возник вопрос хорошая ли это практика хранить всё в одном объекте